# Index out of range error when running a for loop to get values between list items

Tags: python

I am trying to append to an empty list the values in between two list items (1st & 2nd, 3rd & 4th etc. ) I'm running the below code in Jupyter notebook and I see the correct values that I am looking for, but with the index out of range error.  When try to append to a list, I get the same error, but without seeing the output at all.  I have also tried `for x in range(0,len(head_list)):` but I get the same error.

[image]

**Code**

```
head_list = [11,13,35,37,67,72]
final = [] 
x=0 
i=0 
for x in head_list:
    print(list(range(head_list[i]+1,head_list[i+1],1)))
    x=0
    i=i+2
```

```
# desired result: 
[12,36,68,69,70,71]
```

Comment: for i in range(len(head_list)-1), does this work?

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

You get an [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError) because you try to access the index `len(head_list)` in the last iteration of your loop.

### Code example

```
head_list = [11,13,35,37,67,72]
final = [] 

# iterate over the list length taking 2 steps at a time
for i in range(0, len(head_list)-1, 2):
    # concatenate the lists
    final = final + list(range(head_list[i]+1, head_list[i+1]))

print(final)
```

### Output

```
[12, 36, 68, 69, 70, 71]
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This will work.

for range need to bee -1 len of list